# How to get Time Zone of a place in php

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, timezone

I have a formatted address of a place like Bhubaneswar,Odisha,India.How can I get the Time Zone of this place ie "Asia/Calcutta" in php code ?

I can get this using googlemapapi ie Firstly i get the lat and long from this address and using this latitude and longitude and google time zone api key I get the time Zone in javascript .

I want the time zone in purely php code . Can i ?

Thanks in Avd

Comment: have you tried mapping country names to timezones?

Comment: Do you want to set default time as Asia/calcutta??

Comment: Try using services like Yahoo placefinder.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The time zone of a place doesn't change, so if you want the time zone for Calcutta, it is UTC/GMT +5:30 hours. May be you want to do some kind of calculation? or do you want to detect the city from an address and present/store also the time zone? Can you clarify what do you want?

Comment: Did you guys just read the question?

Comment: I think it will be better if you give feedback while press down button

Comment: @hizbul25 read my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can. Try with `file_get_contents()`:

```
<?php
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=20,85&timestamp=1393575206&sensor=false";
$json_timezone = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($json_timezone);
?>
```

This will print:

```
{ "dstOffset" : 0, "rawOffset" : 19800, "status" : "OK", "timeZoneId" : "Asia/Calcutta", "timeZoneName" : "India Standard Time" }
```

Replace the timestamp by the current timestamp or the timestamp corresponding to the date/time you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public function getTimezone($location)
{
    $location = urlencode($location);
    $APIkey = "PLACE API KEY HERE";
    if(!$APIkey){ return false;}
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$location}&key=$APIkey";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    // Get the lat/lng out of the data
    $data = json_decode($data);
    if(!$data) return false;
    if(!is_array($data->results)) return false;
    if(!isset($data->results[0])) return false;
    if(!is_object($data->results[0])) return false;
    if(!is_object($data->results[0]->geometry)) return false;
    if(!is_object($data->results[0]->geometry->location)) return false;
    if(!is_numeric($data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat)) return false;
    if(!is_numeric($data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng)) return false;
    $lat = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    // get the API response for the timezone
    //$timezoneAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location={$lat},{$lng}&timestamp=1331161200&key=AIzaSyBtEwgQX2k0fijo3EsFlOLgXxEvkDpDyeI";

    $timezoneAPI = "http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat={$lat}&lng={$lng}&username=demo";

    $response = file_get_contents($timezoneAPI);
    if(!$response)
        return false;

    $response = json_decode($response);

    if(!is_object($response))
        return false;

    if(isset($response->timezoneId) && !is_string($response->timezoneId)) // If google api, use timeZoneId
        return false;

    return $response->timezoneId;

}
```

Please Use this function

Comment: The question specifically asked for a solution that was "purely php code". This code still uses several external APIs; you've just substituted the GeoNames API for the Google Maps time zone API. (Using the "demo" account, which shouldn't be used in production code…)

Answer (score -1):

In case you find this thread, then take a look at timezoneapi.io.

With the address API you can request an address. The request returns:

- The address
- The timezone (and a lot of related information about the timezone)
- The date / time about the timezone, e.g. what time is it in the timezone, is the timezone in DST, the currency, the capital etc.

In PHP

```
// Get JSON object
$jsondata = file_get_contents("https://timezoneapi.io/api/address/?Hacker+Way+1+Menlo+Park+California");

// Decode
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

// Request OK?
if($data['meta']['code'] == '200'){

    // Example: Get the city parameter
    echo "City: " . $data['data']['addresses']['0']['city'] . "<br>";

    // Example: Get the users time
    echo "Time: " . $data['data']['addresses']['0']['datetime']['date_time_txt'] . "<br>";

}
```

More documentation here:
https://timezoneapi.io/developers/address

Answer (score -1):

**Getting User Timezone using PHP and JS (No API's) (Update on 2020)**

Detecting user timezone is a two-step process:

> 1. Get the timezone offset of the browser with Javascript, and sent it to PHP (via AJAX or something).
> 2. Convert the timezone offset to a valid TZ Database timezone name such as America/New_York,Asia/Kolkata.

**1) Getting the Browser Timezone Offset**

`Javascript` has a `getTimezoneOffset` method which gives timezone difference, in minutes, from current local time to UTC. We need to pass this offset to the server.

It should be noted that `getTimezoneOffset` returns an offset which is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. So we must add an opposite sign (+ or -) to the offset.

```
var timezone_offset_minutes = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
timezone_offset_minutes = timezone_offset_minutes == 0 ? 0 : -timezone_offset_minutes;

// Timezone difference in minutes such as 330 or -360 or 0
console.log(timezone_offset_minutes);
```

**2) In PHP, Convert Timezone Offset in Minutes to a Timezone Name**

You can get the timezone name from timezone offset in minutes through the `timezone_name_from_abbr` function.

```
// This is just an example. In application this will come from Javascript (via an AJAX or something)
$timezone_offset_minutes = 330;  // $_GET['timezone_offset_minutes']

// Convert minutes to seconds
$timezone_name = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $timezone_offset_minutes*60, false);

// Asia/Kolkata
echo $timezone_name;
```

Now when you get the timezone name, you can get date and time relative to the user's timezone :

```
date_default_timezone_set($timezone_name);
```

Source: https://usefulangle.com/post/31/detect-user-browser-timezone-name-in-php